# Make Xcode 4 stop auto staging with git

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4

I hate it that whenever I make a change in Xcode 4 it automatically does a "Git add" command. Is there a way to make this stop?

Comment: -1: The question asks how to stop something that isn't actually happening (as per @Dan Ray's answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Xcode 4's git integration is "broken" in that they tried to present a uniform interface to source control regardless of whether the back-end is git or svn. That means they're supporting only the lowest common denominator of functionality. As a result, use of the index (the "staging area") is out. It always does auto-adds no matter whether you want it to or not.

EDIT: Actually, I don't think it auto-adds. I think it always does `commit -a`. Looking at `git status` on the command line shows me many new and modified files that are NOT staged. But I'm sure if I committed with Xcode they'd all end up in that commit.

Comment: I guess you mean `git status` rather than `svn status` in your last paragraph.

Answer (score 13):

For Xcode 6 this is not an issue anymore. Visit Preferences -> Source Control tab and turn off 'Add and remove files automatically' checkbox

Answer (score 11):

What I do is perform all my git interaction through the command line. Since I can't get Xcode to ignore the fact that my project is under git control, and since therefore I can't get Xcode to stop doing `git add` for every new file I create, when I get to the command line the first thing I do is `git reset` to reset the index. This undoes all the annoying `git add` stuff that Xcode did automatically. Now I'm in charge of what goes into the index and so I get to form my own commits the way I want.

Comment: Good point. I've doing this for a while now too. I never even gave the integrated git tools a chance. I just rightly assumed that they would be poorly implemented.

Comment: I've put in a request thru Apple's bugreporter that they should give us a switch in Xcode to turn off integrated source version control. You could do the same; they are said to respond better if they get more "votes"...

Comment: @matt Are you still using command line for Git instead of Xcode GUI in 2023 ? Just read your _Picturing Git: Conceptions and Misconceptions_ article, it's really well written.

Comment: @Andy Thanks! Yes, the Xcode GUI is even worse in Xcode 15 than it was in Xcode 14 (they did something to the source control navigator which has made it unusable). I rely on the command line, supplemented by tools like `tig`, `difft`, and good old BBEdit. The part of Xcode's source control support that I _do_ use is the blue "change bars" that appear on the left of changed code, and the side by side version of the "code review" interface (oh, and the author/blame annotations).

Answer (score 3):

For me, the solution was this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378745/1078859

TL;DR; remove the repository from xcode's organizer

Answer (score 2):

While the question title says XCode 4 this question appears at the top for many search results related to this issue even in newer versions of XCode.  Here is an answer that addresses newer versions of XCode.  In XCode 6 you can turn off version control by going to XCode --> Preferences --> Source Control Tab and uncheck Enable Source Control.